# Chart with Adjustable Values

Tags: php, jquery, forms, charts

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a web page that allows students to rate aspects of their course or module and the data be sent to an academic?

The features this needs to have are:

- Input fields to rate the module (ideally jQuery Slider)
- Charts software such as High Charts or Google Charts to output the data
- All data sent to server and collated in one diagram showing average values for each of the input areas

Has anyone ever done anything like this before and can recommend how to get started?

Many thanks

Comment: 1. Make a form with multiple sliders for each input. 2. Store it in a database. 3. Retrieve and calculate the average with PHP or SQL. 4. Feed it to Googe Charts/Highcharts.  Seriously, you know what you should be doing, so what's your problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply that's useful. I apologise if the solution to this seems a little too obvious for you, but I haven't actually done anything like this before so wanted to ask for advice on best practice before jumping in. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I was a bit too harsh. But it still comes down to these 4 points I wrote down. If you have a problem with any of them -  add it to the question. The more specific problem, the more and better answers you will get. But listing a couple of feature for your app and asking for recommendations won't get you very far, since it becomes too broad. Even if you get any, they will probably also be too broad to make any use of them. Try to be more specific, and I (and probably others as well) can give you specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution see highcharts great examples: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ its beaty and easy

Comment: Thanks, HighCharts looks great. Would you recommend it over Google Charts, or do you think that either site could be used?